# R package "rEDM": ccm_means function for convergent cross mapping?

Tags: r

I am conducting "convergent cross mapping" analysis for a multivariate data series. Unfortunately, I am struggeling with the function "ccm_means" of the R-package "rEDM". It is "deprecated" and I did not find a proper alternative so far. Do you know any alternative package or function for conducting CCM = convergent cross mapping analysis?

Explicitely, I am talking about this piece of code:

```
library(rEDM)
data(sardine_anchovy_sst)
anchovy_xmap_sst <- ccm(sardine_anchovy_sst, E = 3, lib_column = "anchovy", 
                        target_column = "np_sst", lib_sizes = seq(10, 80, by = 10), num_samples = 100, 
                        random_libs = TRUE, replace = TRUE, silent = TRUE)
sst_xmap_anchovy <- ccm(sardine_anchovy_sst, E = 3, lib_column = "np_sst", target_column = "anchovy", 
                        lib_sizes = seq(10, 80, by = 10), num_samples = 100, random_libs = TRUE, 
                        replace = TRUE, silent = TRUE)
str(anchovy_xmap_sst)
a_xmap_t_means <- ccm_means(anchovy_xmap_sst)
t_xmap_a_means <- ccm_means(sst_xmap_anchovy)
#####--------> ERROR POPS UP HERE

plot(a_xmap_t_means$lib_size, pmax(0, a_xmap_t_means$rho), type = "l", col = "red", 
     xlab = "Library Size", ylab = "Cross Map Skill (rho)", ylim = c(0, 1))
lines(t_xmap_a_means$lib_size, pmax(0, t_xmap_a_means$rho), col = "blue")
legend(x = "topleft", legend = c("anchovy xmap SST", "SST xmap anchovy"), col = c("red", 
                                                                                  "blue"), lwd = 1, bty = "n", inset = 0.02, cex = 0.8)*
```

Thank you very much for ur help.
KR,
Chris